# PostMan - Running collections with data files

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, postman

I have a Json Request using this body :

```
{"ecoleId":{{ecoleId}},"niveauScolaireId":{{niveauScolaireId}},"sectionLinguistiqueId":
{{sectionLinguistiqueId}},"sitesSouhaites":{{siteSouhaites}},"taskId":{{task}}}
```

and this json Data file:

```
[
{
  "env": "dev",

  "enfantId":75801,
  "exerciceId":2421,

 
  "ecoleId":"1",
  "niveauScolaireId":3,
  "sectionLinguistiqueId":61,
  "sitesSouhaites":[{"id":6},{"id":10}]
}
]
```

but when running the tests I have this error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Long` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
```

Comment: Can you clarify  what ```"sitesSouhaites"```should be expecting? The way you have supplied your data, you are implying it needs to expect an array of objects. However, based on your exception and the other attributes, are they supposed to be integer / long value. If so in that case I presume it should be ```"sitesSouhaites":[6,10]```. Also guessing this : ```"ecoleId":"1"``` should be integer not String, If that is the case amend  to ```"ecoleId":1```.  Also you have ```"taskId"``` in the body, is that allowed to be missing, it will be applied as ```null```. If is expected, also add a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that the issue might be with the placeholders and these placeholders are not valid JSON syntax and can cause parsing errors! so you need to replace these placeholders with actual values in your JSON request body!

ok I give you an example but don't forget to replace my digits with the appropriate values you want to use and make sure that the values are of the correct data type like `Long` for numeric values!!!

for example:

```
{
  "ecoleId": 1,
  "niveauScolaireId": 3,
  "sectionLinguistiqueId": 61,
  "sitesSouhaites": [
    {"id": 6},
    {"id": 10}
  ],
  "taskId": 110110
}
```

Comment: placeHolders are Ok, It works until I added "sitesSouhaites" vars